# How to use Masonry in the navigation bar case

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, masonry

I want to use Masonry draw a button below navigation bar 20px，so I use the following code

```
[button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left).with.offset(20);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
    make.top.equalTo(@(self.topLayoutGuide.length + 20));
    make.height.equalTo(@30);
}];
```

but it doesn't work！Unless i change the code like this

```
make.top.equalTo(@84);
```

So i don't want use @84，Are there any other way？Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
make.top.equalTo(@(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20));
```

Comment: i had try,it also doesn't work ,20 should change to 40 ,maybe the status bar has 20px height !    is there something in masonry like topLayoutGuide??

Comment: should change to means ? you wanted below the navigation bar or below the status bar ?

Comment: below the navigation bar. if i use make.top.equalTo(@(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20)) ,the button and the navigation bar next to each other .you can have a try

Comment: please log, self.navigationController to check if it exist and then also print navigationBar frame to confirm its size

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [navigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/navigation-bars/) and [statusBarFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622937-statusbarframe?language=objc) properties for getting top offset.

You can use something like this:

```
CGFloat topbarHeight = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height +
                                (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height ? : 0.0));

// button
[button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker* make) {
    make.height.equalTo(@30);
    make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).with.offset(topbarHeight);
    make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left).with.offset(20);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
}];
```

but it's better to use UIKit's layoutGuides:

```
[topView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    UIView *topLayoutGuide = (id)self.topLayoutGuide;
    make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.bottom);
    make.left.equalTo(self.view);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view);
    make.height.equalTo(@100);
}];
```

**UPDATED**

but it's deprecated now :) **iOS 11.0 and above** we can use the [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide?language=objc) property of UIView instead.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideTop);
} else {
    UIView *topLayoutGuide = (id)self.topLayoutGuide;
    make.top.equalTo(self.mas_topLayoutGuide);
}
```

Comment: ~~make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.mas_bottom)~~ is wrong, should use **make.top.equalTo(self.mas_topLayoutGuide)**